# Запятая перед "чем"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "чем" в предложении: "Ведь мы наверняка знали этот секрет прежде, чем обрели высшие знания".

Answer (score 3):

Предложений сложное, запятая нужна. Чаще она ставится перед всем союзом "прежде чем", но если Вы хотите подчеркнуть значение слова "прежде", вы можете поставить запятую и после него (перед "чем").

*Ведь мы наверняка знали этот секрет прежде, чем обрели высшие знани*я. Или *Ведь мы наверняка знали этот секрет, прежде чем обрели высшие знания".*

Comment: Запятая-то (одна из двух) нужна. Вот насчет сложного предложения.   
"Мы знали, прежде чем обрели". Разве тут не однородные сказуемые?


Comment: Союз "прежде чем" - подчинительный. Знали (когда?), прежде чем обрели. Между однородными членами связь сочинительная. Предложение сложное, вторая часть - неполное предложение.

Comment: Ой, не знаю... Не тянет вторая часть на предложение, даже подсчиненное. Ну да ладно, не принципиально.

Comment: Солидарна с @Ларf. Предложение сложное. Вторая часть - неполное предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Такая же история с союзом потому что и т.п. Запятую можно поставить и перед ним, и перед "что"

Answer (score 0):

Мне не очень нравится сквозящий в ответах либерализм уважаемых коллег. Привлекает известная рекомендация Розенталя располагать  составные союзы "прежде чем, до тех пор пока, с тех пор как, потому что, оттого что, несмотря на то что, ввиду того что, в случае если и др." полностью в придаточном предложении. Исключение составляют случаи, когда интонационно и логически  надо разделить такие союзы на две части, причем первая часть превращается в относительное (указательное ) слово главного предложения. Только в этом случае возможно деление составного союза на две части: Дедушка приказал не будить Танюшу ДО ТЕХ ПОР,пока сама не проснется.